Does adding task nodes make sense in our scenario?
We have an EMR cluster that scales between 3 to 20 core nodes (m5.4xlarge) and has a HDFS replication factor of 3. Most of our job's runtime (about 6.5 or 8.5 hours) is writing data to OpenSeach over HTTP. Data written is around 1.3TB. Does it make sense to add Task nodes to our cluster, given the overhead and stress added to network for sending data to task nodes to be written into OpenSearch over HTTP?
Haven't tried adding Task nodes yet.
